# AttributeError: 'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

## Is there a way to use "pd.read_sql_query" w/ Snowflake?

I am trying to read my snowflake query in a pandas dataframe, however I get an "Attribute Error" stating 'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'shape' (code below) ...

Snowflake python connector works. fetch_pandas_all() works. Once I try reading the query as a pandas dataframe, it breaks.

```
import pyodbc  
import sys  
import os  
import getpass  
import snowflake.connector  
import pyarrow  


conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user='***', password='***', account='***', warehouse='***', database='***', schema='***')
cur = conn.cursor()
tenure = cur.execute(
    """SELECT DISTINCT CT_ID, CT_STRT_DATE, MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('2022-01-01'), TO_DATE(CT_STRT_DATE)) AS TENURE 
    FROM ***.***.****
    WHERE CT_SVC_FREQ != 'OT' AND CT_CNCL_DATE IS NULL AND CT_ID LIKE 'S|%'
    ORDER BY CT_STRT_DATE DESC""")


print(tenure.fetch_pandas_all()) --- This code works fine
```

Once I try to manipulate using pandas, I run into errors...

```
print(tenure.shape) -- breaks w/ "Attribute Error"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this way:

```
df_new = tenure.fetch_pandas_all()
total_rows = df_new.shape[0]
```

Creating a new DF should allow you to run **shape**

Comment: Why are the answers always 3 inches in front of your face??? Thanks! Appreciate the help!